# Split text file into multiple files based on header row

Tags: c#, powershell, ssis

I am trying to split a .txt file  into separate data files from an SSIS Script Task, using header rows starting `FILE|` to denote when a new file should be created.   The row starting `FILE|` is pipe delimited and the  second delimited value is the file name to use.

In the below code I have been able to obtain the file name.  However, I want to be able to write all rows between the `FILE|` header rows to their corresponding file.  E.g., `DataFile1` has all files below the header row written to `DataFile1.txt` until the row header `DataFile2` is hit.

Below is my commented code on how far I've got and what I think I'm missing.  Any help to get me over the line is appreciated:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // The file from my SSIS package containing the unsplit data
        string dataFile = Dts.Variables["User::unsplitDataFile"].Value.ToString();

        // The destination I want to write this to, e.g. \\vSplitDestination\DataFile1.txt:
        string splitDestination = Dts.Variables["User::vSplitDestination"].Value.ToString();

        bool fireAgain = true;

        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataFile);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("FILE"))
            {
                // File Names found
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Info:", line.Split('|','|')[1].ToString(), String.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

                // Create file with file name above ( line.Split('|','|')[1].ToString() ) and fill with all rows until next "FILE" pattern hit.

                // Repeat for all file names

            }

            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

For user "observer" in comments below, attempt at powershell script - answers on this also welcomed:

```
$Path = "\\Transfer"
$InputFile = (Join-Path $Path "unsplit.data")
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)

While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    If ($Line -match "FILE|(.+?)") {
        $OutputFile = $matches[0] + ".txt"
    }

    Add-Content (Join-Path $Path $OutputFile) $Line
}
```

Sample data (so each `FILE|` becomes its own datafile(n).txt file with the rows below in that file)

```
FILE|datafile1|25/04/17
25044|0001|37339|10380|TT75
25045|0001|37339|10398|TT75
25046|0001|78711|15940|TT75
FILE|datafile2|25/04/17
25047|0001|98745|11263|TT75
25048|0001|96960|13011|TT84
FILE|datafile3|25/04/17
25074|0001|57585|13639|TT84
25075|0001|59036|10495|TT84
FILE|datafile4|25/04/17
25076|0001|75844|13956|TT84
25077|0001|17430|01111|TT84
```

Comment: you can also use PowerShell using ExecuteProcessTask instead of using ScriptTask. PowerShell will be much better then the ScriptTask.

Comment: Thanks - I'm weak on powershell.  I've tried a search but not come up with a satisfactory result, I've had an attempt (see addendum to original question) but isn't working, are you able to develop this into an answer here ?

Comment: Ok, I will create a demo package and after I am done I will post that as an answer. Will try to do it Today.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data in the text file.

Comment: @observer added to original question as requested.

Comment: What results are you getting when you run the PowerShell script?

Comment: Hi @JeffZeitlin I get two files, one with the header rows listed and the other with the raw data in it.  I don't want this, I want a separate file per header with the relevant data in it and the file named as above.

Comment: When I build a sample line like yours, and run the match, I get `$matches[0]` returning `FILE` rather than the file name. Consider using something like  `$splits = $line -split "|"; if ($splits[0] -eq "FILE") { $outfile = $splits[1] + ".txt" }; Add-Content -Path $outfile -Value $line`inside your `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 2 errors:

- `-match` needs a RegEx, in a RegEx the unescaped vertical bar denotes an or expression, so you have to escape `|` with a backslash `\|`
- the first matched group in a RegEx is `$matches[1]`
- to match everything between the first two bars I use a negated class

---

```
$Path = "\\Transfer"
$InputFile = (Join-Path $Path "unsplit.data")
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)

While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    If ($Line -match 'FILE\|([^\|]+)') {
        $OutputFile = "$($matches[1]).txt"
    }
    Add-Content (Join-Path $Path $OutputFile) $Line
}
```

Comment: Spot on. Thanks a lot.